# How to get value of email form JWT

Tags: php, jwt, dialogflow-es

Im usign dialogflow to create a booking table assistant.
To get info by user, he need to sign in with google so when finish the conversation i would take uderId value of user.
For take that I use jose-php library so:

```
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *' );
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' );
header( "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true" );
header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );

include('../phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php');
include('../JOSE/JWT.php');
include('../JOSE/URLSafeBase64.php');
$jwt_string = 'userIdtoken';
$jwt = JOSE_JWT::decode($jwt_string);
echo $jwt['JOSE_JWT']['Claims']['email'];
```

the problem is that I recive error printing email value!
How I could get it?

$jwt value result so:

```
JOSE_JWT Object
(
    [header] => Array
        (
            [alg] => RS256
            [kid] => cf022a49e9786148ad0e379cc854844e36c3edc1
            [typ] => JWT
        )

    [claims] => Array
        (
            [iss] => https://accounts.google.com
            [nbf] => 1551435957967
            [aud] => 284549458086-fdoluk70pqkcuh8vj4tj1dou15v444tiua.apps.googleusercontent.com
            [sub] => 1092379345381822971290339
            [email] => dasdasddas@gmail.com
            [email_verified] => 1
            [name] => frank rossi
            [picture] => https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-79eVyjn_YU8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAPBs/uvq_fruLiB0/s96-c/photo.jpg
            [given_name] => Federico
            [family_name] => Idsfdsfdsf
            [iat] => 1545351958267
            [exp] => 155143534961867
            [jti] => 428254345532cddf49dec17d24ace2e6f45f8af4b14b2
        )

    [signature] => 'somthing'
    [raw] => 'somthing'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like the problem is a typo. You wrote `$jwt['JOSE_JWT']['Claims']['email'];`, but the key is `claims`, not `Claims`.

Also, `$jwt` seems to be an object of class `JOSE_JWT`, not an array. So using it with subscript operator is not possible just like that. You should instead access its properties:

```
$jwt->claims['email']
```

Comment: the response is Fatal error: Cannot use object of type JOSE_JWT as array in xxxx.php on line 13 and the line 13 is the last echo

Comment: ok this dont get error, but the output is not decoded....why? Because if make print_r($jwt) I see the array that I wrote

Comment: What do you mean by “not decoded”? What is the output?

Comment: something like that: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImNmMDIyYTQ5ZTk3ODYxNDhhZDBlMzc5Y2M4NTQ4NDRlMzZjM2VkYzEiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJo

Comment: Do you have any documentation for this `JOSE_JWT` class?

Comment: I think the problem is the value of $jwt because if i try print_r($jwt) show me the result, but print_r($jwt,true) no!